# How can I change this bit of text to white within Eclipse/CFPlugin?

Tags: eclipse, ide, coldfusion, customization

Try as I might, I just can't find the place to edit the color of ColdFusion variables within Eclipse. I absolutely hate writing against a white background, as it wears out my eyes, and so I'm trying to migrate to a customized IDE that will be easier to read and easy to debug syntactically. Here's some example code.

[image: ColdFusion Example]

As you can see in the top row, the variable names are still black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - I used to use CFeclipse, check in Project | Properties

this is a Charlie Arhart blog with links to legit cf developers specifically using CFEclipse.

The list of CFEclipse category feeds in this post:

http://carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2007/7/10/come_read_70_CFEclipse_bloggers

this is the guy who wrote most of it - his blog on CFEclipse, Mark Drew http://www.markdrew.co.uk/blog/archives.cfm/category/cfeclipse

This guy has a useful lists of shortcuts for CFEclipse - some of them formatting, like
[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[Z] - color picker...
http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/7/10/Important-shortcuts-for-Eclipse-and-CFEclipse

Finally, a user group to ask the question if you don't get good answer here
http://groups.google.com/group/cfeclipse-users/browse_thread/thread/6d704824f593a0c9#